# Can't change DATETIME format

Tags: php, mysql, date

How do I change the format of date + time in a database when calling it?

Currently it's:

```
YYYY-MM-DD Days:HH:MM
```

But I need it to be:

```
DD-MM-YYYY Days:HH:MM
```

I tried this approach

```
FORMAT(s.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

But it gives me something like this:

```
20,130,618,232,643
```

Because it has time included I think.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And which SQL client to display the data?

Comment: MySQL and I call it with PHP

Comment: what is the type of s.date

Comment: It's DATETIME in this format 2013-06-18 23:26:43 I want it to be 18-06-2013 23:26:43 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT(date, format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(s.date,'%d-%m-%Y')
```